# Command pattern with batch finish method

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous, data-synchronization, asynchronous-testing

To chain a execution of a batchable object, I pass the batchable contructor a `ICommand`.

```
public interface ICommand {
    void Execute();
}
```

When testing this approach I create a test `ICommand` which just flags when it has been executed.

```
private class TestCommand implements ICommand
{
    public boolean HasExecuted
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TestCommand()
    {
        HasExecuted = false;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        HasExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that according to the execution log the `Execute` method is called as expected and `HasExecuted` is assigned a value of `true`, but after `Test.stopTest();` is invoked the value of `HasExecuted` is assigned back to `false` by some strange (impossible) method.

```
14:57:16:042 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [56]|this.HasExecuted|true|0x56461b13
...
14:57:16:053 METHOD_EXIT [48]|System.Test.stopTest()
14:57:16:053 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [EXTERNAL]|this|{"HasExecuted":false}|0x43c87c0c
**14:57:16:053 EXCEPTION_THROWN [51]|System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: true, Actual: false**
```

Is this normal behaviour for for apex to prevent changing changing object values by reference over async execution contexts, or is something else happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference isn't valid in asynchronous execution. Specifically, when you call System.schedule, System.enqueueJob, or Database.executeBatch, the class is *serialized* and put in to a queue. This effectively makes a *copy* of the object, not the original. A more particular example might be useful:

```
public class Example implements Queueable {
  public String value;
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    System.debug(value);
  }
}
...
Example e = new Example();
e.value = 'Hello';
System.enqueueJob(e);
e.value = 'World';
// output will be "Hello"
Test.stopTest();
// output will be "World"
System.debug(e.value);
```

Since the *copy* is what actually runs, the original doesn't get modified.

The typical scenario, if you want to use this model for unit tests, is to set a private static test visible variable:

```
@TestVisible static Boolean hasExecuted = false;
...
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
  hasExecuted = true;
}
...
  System.enqueueJob(q);
  Test.stopTest();
  System.assert(Example.hasExecuted,'Expected execution of queueable class');
```